# Angular 5 - HTTP Interceptor Intercepts 401 as status code 0

Tags: html, css, angular, http

I'm currently unable to intercept 401 status & re-direct to Login page as most applications do,
my intercept is pretty much the boilerplate

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        request = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });

        return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            retry(0),
            takeUntil(this.httpCancelService.onCancelPendingRequests()), ==> cancels out pending request on route change
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    this.authenticationService.logout() ===> logout incase of 401     
                }  else if (request.url.indexOf("assets") == -1) {
                    this.alertService.error('An unexpected error occurred, please try again later');
                }

                return throwError(errorMessage)
            })
        )
    }
```

the browser is capturing request as 401 on Network tab yet on this Angular interceptor,
we get 'error.status' as '0' & 'error.message' as 'Unknown Error'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Status code 0 means it's probably a CORS error. This means the response from the backend server was missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. When the backend is correctly configured you will be able to access the actual error code.

Comment: any idea why it still shows as '401' in the network tab of browser & not in the Angular, since im trying to reason it out :)

Comment: Check out the response of the 401 request in the network tab. It should be empty. It is some weird browser magic. It shows 401 but response is empty.

Comment: thnx! @bahadrdsr this seemed to be the issue with server side reverse proxy not adding CORS headers for http error codes

Answer (score -2):

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if ((error.status === 401)) {
                    console.log("HTTP 401")
                }
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
}
```